# Proving the Existence of Locally Inertial Coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, notation, textbook-erratum

This question is regarding the proof of the existence of locally inertial coordinates, outlined in Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry book (Chapter 2, page 74). In particular, I believe that extra factors of $2$ or $\frac{1}{2}$ should be present in the Taylor expansions the proof uses - these are later flagged in red. I've checked the errata [here](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/spacetimeandgeometry/).

Given a manifold $M$, at any point $p \in M$, we want to show that we can move from a coordinate system $x^{\mu}$ to $x^{\hat{\mu}}$ such that:

1. $g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}}(p) = \eta_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}}$
2. $\partial_{\hat{\sigma}} g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}}(p) = 0$

For simplicity, choose the origin of both sets of coordinates to coincide with $p$. We also know the metric components transform like:

$$g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\nu}}} g_{\mu \nu} \tag{2.48}$$

Carroll now Taylor expands both sides of this equation to show that there are enough degrees of freedom to satisfy constraints 1 and 2. However, I have obtained extra factors of 2 when trying to perform the expansion myself.

> The expansion of the old coordinates $x^{\mu}$ looks like
> $$x^{\mu} = \left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}}\right)_p x^{\hat{\mu}} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial^2 x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}_1} \partial x^{\hat{\mu}_2}}\right)_p x^{\hat{\mu}_1} x^{\hat{\mu}_2} + \dots$$
> [...] Then using some extremely schematic notation, the expansion of $(2.48)$ to second order is
> $$(\hat{g})_p + (\hat{\partial} \hat{g})_p \hat{x} + (\hat{\partial} \hat{\partial} \hat{g})_p \hat{x}\hat{x} = \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} g\right)_p + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}}g + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \hat{\partial}g \right)_p \hat{x} + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^3 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}}g + \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}}g + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}} \hat{\partial}g + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \hat{\partial} \hat{\partial}g \right)_p \hat{x} \hat{x}$$

I agree with the expansion of $x^{\mu}$, but disagree with the expansions of the left and right hand side of $(2.48)$. I'm introducing a book-keeping parameter $\epsilon$ to help track the order of particular terms to make them easier to group together.

**Looking at the LHS:**

$$g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}} (x^{\hat{\alpha}}) = g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}} (0) + \epsilon \partial_{\hat{\sigma}} g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}} (0) x^{\hat{\sigma}} + \epsilon^2 \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\hat{\sigma}} \partial_{\hat{\rho}} g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}} (0)x^{\hat{\sigma}}x^{\hat{\rho}} \tag{A} $$

Therefore, I would have actually expected the LHS to be $$(\hat{g})_p + (\hat{\partial} \hat{g})_p \hat{x} + \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} (\hat{\partial} \hat{\partial} \hat{g})_p \hat{x}\hat{x}$$

**Looking at the RHS:**

The expansion of $g_{\mu \nu}$ follows (A), but with $g_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}}$ replaced with $g_{\mu \nu}$.

$$\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}} = \left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}}\right)_p + \epsilon \left(\frac{\partial^2 x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}} \partial x^{\hat{\sigma}}}\right)_p x^{\hat{\sigma}} + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 \left(\frac{\partial^3 x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}} \partial x^{\hat{\sigma}} \partial x^{\hat{\rho}}}\right)_p x^{\hat{\sigma}} x^{\hat{\rho}} $$

We can now substitute both these expansions into $(2.48)$.

- $\epsilon^0$ terms: the only way to get such a term is by multiplying by the $\epsilon^0$ parts of the expansion in each of the 3 terms that are being multiplied on the RHS of $(2.48)$. This corresponds to $g_{\mu \nu}(p) \left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\nu}}}\right)_p$ in agreement with Carroll.
- $\epsilon$ terms: we need to get an order $\epsilon$ term from one of the multiplicative factors on the RHS of $(2.48)$ and multiply it by the $\epsilon^0$ terms from the expansion of the other factors. I believe we should have:

$$\left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial^2 x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\nu}} \partial x^{\hat{\sigma}}}\right)_p g_{\mu \nu}(p) x^{\hat{\sigma}} + \left(\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\nu}}}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial^2 x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}} \partial x^{\hat{\sigma}}}\right)_p g_{\mu \nu}(p) x^{\hat{\sigma}} + \left(\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\mu}}}\right)_p \left(\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\hat{\nu}}}\right)_p \partial_{\hat{\sigma}} g_{\mu \nu}(p) x^{\hat{\sigma}}$$

Since $g_{\mu \nu} = g_{\nu \mu}$, this corresponds to:

$$\left(\color{red}{2} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}}g + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \hat{\partial}g \right)_p \hat{x}$$

in disagreement with Carroll.

- $\epsilon^2$ terms: using similar reasoning to above, I believe that Carroll's $\hat{x} \hat{x}$ coefficient should actually be

$$\left(\color{red}{2} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^3 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}}g + \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}}g + \color{red}{2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \hat{x} \partial \hat{x}} \hat{\partial}g + \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \frac{\partial x}{\partial \hat{x}} \hat{\partial} \hat{\partial}g \right)_p$$

**Summary of Question**

I was wondering if these extra factors in the expansion of $(2.48)$ that I've highlighted in red are actually correct; it doesn't affect the overall argument (which counts the number of free parameters we have), but I'm still quite confused why these identified factors aren't present.

Comment: " Then using some extremely schematic notation, ..."

Comment: @mmeent Wouldn't absorbing these extra factors of 2 or 1/2 into the "schematic notation" make it inconsistent? I can see why this would be possible to do if there was a single global factor multiplying every term, but this is not the case.

Comment: As you note yourself, the factors do not matter for the actual argument.